# Is there a more natural way of saying "accompany someone with his singing"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> Elvis stepped up on the stage and accompanied Madonna with this
> singing.

Is there a better way of saying this? It's a mouthful and it sounds a bit robotic and non-natural.

Comment: The title says "his singing", the quote says "this singing". What is the source of the quote?

Comment: I wrote it, because I couldn't find an example.

Comment: You might say "accompanied Madonna vocally." Or just "sang along with her".

Comment: 'Accompanying a singer' usually means playing the piano (or sometimes another instrument) for them.